# where is documentation of Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

I saw `have_selector` first time today. I want to learn it's options, so I went to official site.

But I can't find it anywhere.

- [rspec-core](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/2.6.4/frames)
- [rspec-expectation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/frames)
- [rspec-rails](http://rdoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/2.6.1/frames)
- [Relish](http://relishapp.com/rspec)

I used the search feature in each of the above sites, but in vain.

It's just a small, common method, right? But I can't even read it's API... where is it?

**Edit**: I use Webrat. Now I know `have_selector` is from it. But seems no useful documentation.

Comment: Are you using Capybara or Webrat?

Comment: Sorry for carelessness. I find [it](http://rdoc.info/gems/webrat/0.7.3/Webrat/Matchers#have_selector-instance_method) finally. Though I think this document is totally useless... the parameters are `name`, `attributes` and `&block`, but it says `expected`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is one of Capybara's Rspec matchers: [Capybara::RSpecMatchers#have_selector](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_selector-instance_method).

You can use that method for querying the page for the existence of certain elements using css or xpath notation (examples from Capybara's Readme):

```
page.should have_selector('table tr')
page.should have_selector(:xpath, '//table/tr')
```

Comment: Thanks you. But... it doesn't tell me how to use this method.

Comment: Does this mean I shouldn't try to find info on rubydoc.info? (BTW, I use webrat, not capybara)

Comment: @Lai: well, you should try, but, unfortunantly, not all gems have exhaustive API documentation.

Comment: After searching and searching, I guess I found [treasure](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers:has_selector%3F) finally.